# How can I get a sample DB with basic users profile on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, machine-learning, nlp

I am developing an app that allows people to sign in with their Facebook profile. The app will retrieve users basic Facebook profile and will try to classify them by that raw data.
Does anyone know of a sample DB with users ( can be fake users) basic Facebook profile?

Comment: I think you should ask many people just to install it and retrieve the data. I don't think the information in the fake accounts would help you ...

Comment: Facebook enables you to create fake users for your application. You can modify their profiles in order to have what you want, but it may take time if you want a respectable dataset. You may have more luck on opendata.stackexchange.com